# How to switch carriers inside ios app

Tags: iphone, ios

Is it possible for an iOS app to switch the phone carrier used by the phone using Apple-approved APIs (i.e. without a jailbreak)?

Comment: Switch the phone carrier??? What? How would you do that. Through code you would magically insert a new sim-card, and create a new plan for the user, not to mention perhaps change device compatibility is you switch to an incompatible service?

Comment: Needing it If you go outside.If one carrier cooperate with the other. They can switch with each other. So is it possible to switch to the designated phone carrier inside app?

Comment: I have never heard of this before. One carrier cooperating with another carrier. Could you give an example. It's not like AT&T is going to allow an AT&T iPhone to work with say Verizon. I'm pretty confused by this question.

Comment: If you go outside, there will be some 3G carriers options for you. If I know one carrier can switch to the other carrier. I can do it for the user in the app.

Comment: I seriously doubt there is an API for that, if that is even possible, I'm just taking your word for it. Apple would not supply something like that. That would cause problems for the carriers, and even if you found a private API, Apple would not allow in the app store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carriers don't simply work that way. The iPhone activates with one carrier and only one carrier at a time. If you mean handing off carriers as in going from AT&T in the US and then crossing into Canada and using Rogers network, the iPhone will do that by itself because that API is not public. Not only do apps not have access to that functionality but it doesn't really apply to an iPhone app to even execute that function. But the iPhone can only activate with the Carrier Sim card that is inserted if it is a GSM carrier or by a single CDMA carrier at the time of boot. So a iPhone can not simply "choose" to jump on to any available network unless authorized by the carrier and allowed by internal Apple code. Not only are different cell networks broadcasted differently, but a cell network will not allow a phone on even if it is compatible if you do not have access to it (sim card, active plan ex.) So this functionality is not possible for an iphone app.

Answer (score 0):

On a GSM phone, there do exist SIM cards that can be programmed to handle multiple IMSI and KI values, allowing the phone to select between multiple networks. I don't believe there is any API to do this exposed to developers in iOS.